# Is there a way I can get Intellij to underline Groovy errors?

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

With some groovy errors, Intellij reports the errors in the messages window, but doesn't underline the code in red in the editor.  Is there a way to get it to do this?

Example:

```
static boolean example(){ x = 5 }
```

With that code, when I try to compile the messages window gives an error `Apparent variable 'x' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class.`

Is it possible for IntelliJ to also underline the error in the editor (and maybe the project window to show what file the error is in too)?

Answer (score 1):

While IDEA on-the-fly code analyzer can detect 99% errors in the Java code without even running a compiler, it's much harder to do for dynamic languages like Groovy. So, you have to actually build your project in order to see all the compilation errors (use Build | Make).

Analyzer may be improved and will start to detect more errors in the future updates.

Comment: Aww :( - Eclipse takes any errors that the compiler outputs, and underlines the respective source code in red automatically.  Doesn't seem like doing this should be that hard, since the compiler outputs the line and column number that the error is on.

Comment: It's one of the core differences between IDEA and Eclipse. While Eclipse runs compiler every time to update errors information, IDEA does it much faster and on-the-fly. You can get the same behavior as in Eclipse by mapping Save keyboard shortcut to Build | Make, so every time you want to save your code, it will actually save and compile it showing all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use customize highlight level to suppress some warnings on my android layout files.

[image: before]

[image: Change to Syntax from Inspection - default]

[image: Right click on scrollbar for the options]

P.S I love Intellij for android development :)